# My heroes stop gaining xp after level 13?

Tags: heroville

Why does this happen, And how can I fix my heroes to get more exp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your heroes only gain a certain max level per dungeon. Once you get a new dungeon and your hero decides to explore it, they will start leveling again.